# Hiding FragmentStatePagerAdapter and SlidingTabs

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How to hide FragmentStatePagerAdapter, I mean I created sliding tabs with this adapter and I want to hide everything and create new Fragment in whole screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use ".setVisibility (View.GONE)"?

Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29

Comment: so then I can do something like that getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activityContainer, new TestFragment()).commit(); ?

Comment: Wait, i got confused. You cannot hide a PagerAdapter. If you need hide a View and perform a "getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activityContainer, new TestFragment()).commit();" on this view, you can.